# How do I not exceed the bounds of the array in Vigenere cipher?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, vigenere

After a 4th char, my program crashes, returning this error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array. at
>   System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index) at
>   Caesar_Cipher.Program.Main(String[] args)

I have really no idea how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Text;  

namespace vigenere_Cipher {  
    class Program {  
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            string text = string.Empty;
            string key = string.Empty;

            Console.Write("Enter the keyword: ");
            key = Console.ReadLine();
            for(int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
            {
                if(char.IsLetter(key[i]))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("a key must be alphabetical!");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Enter plaintext: ");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            int counter = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j <= text.Length; j++)
            {
                if(counter <= text.Length)
                {
                    counter ++;
                }
                if(char.IsLetter(text[j]))
                {
                if(char.IsUpper(text[j]))
                {
                    Console.Write("Encrypted string: " + Convert.ToChar(((text[j] + key[counter] -65)% 26) + 65));
                }
                if(char.IsLower(text[j]))
                {

                    Console.Write("Encrypted string: " + Convert.ToChar(((text[j] + key[counter]-97)%26) + 97)); 

                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C# are indexed `0...array,Length-`, so all your boundary checks should be like `f(counter <= text.Length -1)`

Comment: I'd also recommend learing how to debug your program, the mistake is quite easy to spot if you follow your program step-by-step and examine the variables values.

Comment: I have added a "-1" but it still doesn't work, still crashes the program with same error :/

Comment: There are two places that have this problem: the way you cap `counter` variable and `j` in the encryption loop.